# Code Igniter .otf custom fonts

Tags: css, codeigniter, fonts

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Placeholder-Font';
  src: url('<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/fonts/Placeholder-Font.otf') format("opentype");
}

* {
    font-family: Placeholder-Font !important;
}
```

When I put this in my css file, making sure the directories and such are correct, my browser (Chrome) defaults to Times Roman for the font. No sure what I am doing wrong here.

I have checked the directories, file-names etc.

Comment: You agree you use PHP in a CSS file ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't used `<?php echo base_url() ?>` but use `../` that mean up on dir.